# float data transmit and receive with tcpip matlab?

Tags: matlab, tcp, gnuradio

I am trying to transmit and receive data over TCP/IP (interfacing with GNU Radio):

```
data = rand(1,128);
t = tcpip('127.0.0.1',2012,'Timeout', 120);
s = whos('data');
set(t,'OutputBufferSize',s.bytes);
fopen(t);
fwrite(t,data,'double')
m=tcpip('127.0.0.1',2022,'Timeout', 120);
set(m,'InputBufferSize',s.bytes)
fopen(m);
fread(m)
```

When I read my data, these are all 0 or 1, I need to get the float data that I am transmitting for my application. Could someone please tell me how to do that?

Comment: why not convert to ASCII first? it will be slightly slower but easier to code.

Comment: in other words, use num2str before sending, and str2num after receiving

Comment: actually I need to transmit float numbers (eg. 0.1067), this would vary from (0 to 1). Here the data actually represents OFDM signal in time domain. I really need to transmit fractional number, eventually this would transmit through USRPs.
This would be really helpful to me if you could tell me if there is any way to transmit float data over tcpip on matlab. Is there any other function for that. here I am interfacing matlab with gnuradio companion.

Comment: one more thing that I missed..
s = whos('data'); %i mistakenly put tx_data there

Comment: @SanjoyBasak, you can edit your original post to correct your mistake or add information ;-)

Comment: @SanjoyBasak: GNU Radio internally uses (you can change that, but I know of no blocks that actually do that) single precision `float` rather than `double`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate your issue with all zeros or ones, but I think that you need to use one of the additional input arguments to [`icinterface/fread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/fread.html). Here's a simple example:

```
data = rand(128, 1);
echotcpip('on', 2012);
t = tcpip('127.0.0.1', 2012, 'Timeout', 120);
bytes_per_double = 8;
set(t, 'InputBufferSize', bytes_per_double*numel(data), ...
       'OutputBufferSize', bytes_per_double*numel(data));
fopen(t);
fwrite(t,data(:),'double');
data_out=fread(t, t.InputBufferSize/bytes_per_double, 'double'); % Read in as doubles
echotcpip('off');
fclose(t);
delete(t);
isequal(data, data_out)
```

The values in `data` and `data_out` should both be doubles and equal to each other.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code worked wonderfully. Actually previously what i read was, I can only transmit uint8 data through tcpip, so the conversion from float gave me 0 or 1 always.
Your code is worked wonderfully. Have a great day, thanks a lot for helping..:)

Comment: Hi, I need little more help. I actually need to control the sampling rate here. Would you please suggest me how can I do that.

time=10; 

i=1;

tic

while (toc<time)    

fwrite(t,data(:),'double');

pause(0.001);

data_out(:,i)=fread(m, m.InputBufferSize/bytes_per_double, 'double'); 

i=i+1;

end

I am using this loop, to send transmit signal multiple times and receive the signal for further processing. I used pause command for controlling data rate. But this is not really working well, with usrps. I need to control sampling rate (eg. 1MHz or 2MHz) Can you suggest me what can I include here.